# AttributeError: can't set attribute for workbook

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

So I have the followiing code where I am writing to an already existing excel file:

```
book = load_workbook(file_path)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
```

I am getting an error at line

writer.book = book as

```
writer.book = book

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

And the worse thing is this error is happening on my colleagues mac machine but not on my windows machine. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 8):

<s>@P-TATE's answer worked for me. I encountered the exact same issue as @bella when running `1.5.0` but not when running `1.4.4`. I found the following in the [release notes for 1.5.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html#excelwriter-attributes)</s>

> All attributes of `ExcelWriter` were previously documented as not
> public. However some third party Excel engines documented accessing
> `ExcelWriter.book` or `ExcelWriter.sheets`, and users were utilizing
> these and possibly other attributes. Previously these attributes were
> not safe to use; e.g. modifications to `ExcelWriter.book` would not
> update `ExcelWriter.sheets` and conversely. In order to support this,
> pandas has made some attributes public and improved their
> implementations so that they may now be safely used. ([GH45572](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/45572))
>
> The following attributes are now public and considered safe to access.
>
> - `book`
> - `check_extension`
> - `close`
> - `date_format`
> - `engine`
> - `if_sheet_exists`
> - `sheets`
> - `supported_extensions`
>
> The following attributes have been deprecated. They now raise a
> `FutureWarning` when accessed and will be removed in a future version.
> Users should be aware that their usage is considered unsafe, and can
> lead to unexpected results.
>
> - `cur_sheet`
> - `handles`
> - `path`
> - `save`
> - `write_cells`

## EDIT:

So after a lot (*lot*) of struggling with this, I've found a solution that works for me and might work for others.

As referenced [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/48780#issuecomment-1260087625), the philosophy of the Pandas team is to make the book (and sheets) setters private, and push those responsibilities onto the Excel engine to implement.

The solution that worked for me is to copy the template excel file to a new file using python, eg:

```py
import shutil

output_path = shutil.copy(template_path, output_path)
```

- Then, load `output_path` as the workbook when you instantiate `ExcelWriter`. Therefore, there is no need to call `openpyxl.load_workbook()` at all, and also no need to copy the `.book` or `.sheets` attributes.
- Also, ensure that you set the `mode` and `if_sheet_exists` flags as follows (see [the docs for more info](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas.ExcelWriter)):

```py
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(
    output_path,
    engine="openpyxl",
    mode="a",
    if_sheet_exists="overlay",
)
```

- Finally be sure to remove any references to `book` (if you had any previously), which was a particularly subtle bug I encountered. All my code to modify Tables, defined names, refs, etc. within the workbook had been applied to the `book` variable which was a workbook instance returned by `openpyxl.load_workbook()`. This variable was then assigned to the `ExcelWriter` instance's `book` attribute with: `writer.book = book` just as you did. However, this is just a reference to the same object in memory, so modifying `book` and `ExcelWriter.book` have the same effect, and my code happened to act on `book`. However, if you make the changes described above, you will no longer have the `book` variable to modify, so you simply use `writer.book` to interact with the workbook, as in `writer.book.defined_names.get(defined_name).attr_text = ref`, instead of `book.defined_names.get(defined_name).attr_text = ref`.

Hope this helps

Comment: So I am guessing it wont work for newer versions but will work for older versions ?

Comment: @Bella the code in your original question will not work going forward. Pandas has made it clear that directly accessing `book` and `sheets` is not allowed. I've edited my original response with a simple solution that worked for me and doesn't rely on any private methods or setters that are being deprecated.

Comment: It works for pandas 2.2.1

Answer (score 6):

I have found that the key is to use writer.workbook instead of writer.book in code here: 
writer.workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx') 
and to add options in: 
pd.ExcelWriter(   ...    , mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay')

```py
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)

# create new excel file
df_empty = pd.DataFrame()
df_empty.to_excel('test.xlsx')

# ... with a sheet name
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ex_sheet = workbook['Sheet1']
ex_sheet.title = 'Tmp'
workbook.save('test.xlsx')

# prepare a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'],
                   'Column2': [100, 170, 140, 160]})

# insert a dataframe into an excel sheet
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay')
writer.workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Tmp', index=False, header=True, startrow=3, startcol=3)

writer.save()
```

I use python 3.8; openpyxl: 3.0.10; pandas: 1.5.0

Comment: writer.close() works for me instead of writer.save()

Answer (score 0):

Double check your dependency versions on each machine using "pip list". Had the same problem and it was caused by pandas version being different on each machine.