# Is there a way to copy a file to memory to edit it?

Tags: python, pandas, bytesio

I am sending pandas dataframes by e-mail as excel files.

Until now, I used pandas 1.5.3, which let me copy the workbook from a template excel file to my `ExcelWriter`'s workbook. I would create a buffer, that I would use as my `ExcelWriter`'s `path` parameter,  so that I could insert the dataframe's data with the writer and then return what would be my e-mail attachment by returning `buffer.getbuffer()`.

Here is a simplified sample of my old code (I have no idea whether it is good practice to use a BytesIO object for this kind of things) :

```py
def insert_template(dataframe) :
    path_template= f"templates\foo.xlsx"
    
    buffer = BytesIO()
    
    book = load_workbook(path_fichier_modele)
    
    with ExcelWriter(buffer, engine="openpyxl") as writer:
        writer.book = book
        sheet_name = book.sheetnames[0]
        book.close()
        
        dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
        
        buffer.seek(0)
    return buffer.getbuffer()
```

Now that I use pandas 2.x, I can no longer assign to `writer.book`, which forces me to copy my template file first (following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73990711/16880681)), then edit this file and send it by e-mail.

Here is a simplified sample of my new code :

```py
def insert_template(dataframe) :
    path_template = f"templates\foo.xlsx"
    file_path = shutil.copy(path_template, '.\\')

    with ExcelWriter(file_path, engine="openpyxl", mode="a", if_sheet_exists="overlay") as writer:
        sheet_name = writer.book.sheetnames[0]

        dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)

    return file_path
```

The Issue is that now that I have to use `shutil.copy` (which requires path-like or string objects as parameters), I have to create and delete a file in my directory, which bugs me a lot. Is there no way to work with a file in memory ? If so, what is the best practice ?

Comment: PSA: Backslashes in double-quoted strings are not always going to work out as you want. Here `\f` means "vertical line feed".

Comment: How is `path_fichier_modele` defined?

Comment: @tadman I know, I rewrote a simplified version of my code for it to be more understandable in this context, I also edited out all the error catching, it's not meant to be working perfectly, just get the point across. Thanks though, you're absolutely right

Comment: @NickODell sorry, forgot to translate it as all of my variable names were originally in french. it's fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a different shutil function, `shutil.copyfileobj()` to do this.

Example:

```py
import shutil
from io import BytesIO


buf = BytesIO()
with open('test.txt', 'rb') as f_in:
    shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, buf)
```

After that, buf will contain the contents of the file test.txt.

You may also need `buf.seek(0)` to reset the position of the read/write pointer.

Comment: Thanks ! I've been stuck on this for some time now. Seeing you did it in your answer, I take it using BytesIO for this is good practice ?

Comment: If you want to avoid file IO, BytesIO is the way to go. The only disadvantage I can think of is that BytesIO has to hold the entire file in memory at once. That's unavoidable if you want to avoid file IO. If you're willing to pay the cost of file IO, tempfile.TemporaryFile is a good alternative.

Comment: I've been looking around on google and I didn't find what the 'cost' of fileIO is. If fileIO is better optimized for this, why would I want to avoid it ?

Comment: File IO has a performance cost. For example, on a benchmark which opens a file, writes ten bytes, then reads it back, doing that with a real file takes 52.9 µs, and doing it with BytesIO takes 0.651 µs. This gap narrows as you get to larger files: for a benchmark which writes 1MB and reads it takes, doing that with a real file takes 1.6 ms, but doing it with BytesIO takes 1.28 ms.